# How do I stop this div from sitting on top of the scrollbar without breaking my JQuery ScrollTo plug-in?

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, overflow, scrollto

I am having a little bit of trouble with a website I'm building. I am using the jQuery plug-in "scroll to" as the website is one complete page with different sections. Now I am trying to keep the navigation bar fixed at the top of the page when the user scrolls down, but at the moment it is sitting over the top of the scrollbar.

I found an answer for how to stop it sitting on top of the scrollbar, which said that I should remove "overflow:auto;" from the 'wrapper' div, but somehow, this killed my ScrollTo plug in, and the links no longer worked.

I want one scrollbar on the right hand side of the page, that users can use to scroll down, but I want the big white navigation bar to stay at fixed at the top.

My website can be downloaded from this link > http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14917277/YW4YW%20Website.zip - 
It is only a small website so will not take two seconds to download.

Any help is HUGELY appreciated, thanks a load guys and girls!

Comment: Reproduce a simplified representation of your problem on a live demo site, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), rather than asking us to 'download your website.' Bring ***relevant*** code inline with the question, jQuery, CSS and html.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David. I asked a question on this website before, and so I wasn't sure of how best to go about it. I'll be sure to bear that in mind for the future. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are putting your content in a wrapper overflowing div? This is happening because the wrapper has a z-index that is lower than the top bar. Remove the wrapper. Just let the content overflow normally!

Replace your index file with this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.panel').click(function () {

        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        current = $(this);

        $(document).scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);        

        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });

});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_height = height * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_height);

    $('body .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('body').css({width: width, height: mask_height});
    $(document).scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

}

</script>
<title>Young Women 4 Young Women - Breast Cancer Support Group - Southmead Hospital, Bristol</title>
</head>
<body>



<div id="top-wrap">
<div id="top-bar"></div> <!-- CLOSE TOP-BAR -->

<div id="navigation-wrapper">
    <div id="navigation-bar">
        <div id="navigation-main">
    <a href="#item1" class="panel">HOME</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#item2" class="panel">ABOUT THE GROUP</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#item3" class="panel">SCHEDULE</a>
</div>  <!-- CLOSE NAVIGATION-MAIN -->

<div id="navigation-main-2">
    <a href="#item4" class="panel">IN THE NEWS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#item5" class="panel">LINKS</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#item6" class="panel">GET IN TOUCH</a>
        </div> <!-- CLOSE NAVIGATION-MAIN-2 -->
   </div> <!-- CLOSE NAVIGATION-BAR -->
</div> <!-- CLOSE NAVIGATION-WRAPPER -->


<div id="emblem"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/emblem.png" alt="Young Women 4 Young Women" /></a></div> <!-- CLOSE EMBLEM -->
</div> <!-- CLOSE TOP-WRAP -->



        <div id="item1" class="home-area">
        <a name="item1"></a>
            <div class="content">

                <div class="home-header-wrap">
                    <div class="home-pad"></div>
                    <div class="home-header-image"><div class="home-cleardiv"></div><h1>YOUNGWOMEN4YOUNGWOMEN.COM</h1></div>
                    <div class="home-pad"></div>
                </div>
<div class="justify"><span class="text">Young Women 4 Young Women is a </span><span class="red-text">support group</span><span class="text"> for women who have been affected by breast cancer. We meet once a month at Southmead Hospital in </span><span class="red-text">Bristol</span><span class="text"> for a chat and a cup of tea.<br /><br />
Over the past </span><span class="red-text">eleven years</span><span class="text"> we have welcomed women of all ages with a wide range of experiences. Whether you are looking for friendship, understanding, comfort, encouragement, laughter, company, support, compassion, of just </span><span class="red-text">somebody to talk to</span><span class="text"> who knows what it's like, we're here for you.</span>
<br /><br />
<div class="center"><span class="text">The kettles on so come on in!</span></div></div>


                </div>
             </div>



        <div id="item2" class="about-area">
            <a name="item2"></a>
            <div class="content">

                <div class="about-us-header-wrap">
                    <div class="about-us-pad"></div>
                    <div class="about-us-header-image"><div class="about-us-cleardiv"></div><h1>WHO ARE WE, AND WHAT DO WE DO?</h1></div>
                </div>
<br />

<ul class="box">
  <li><img src="images/portrait.png"></li>
</ul>


                      <div class="divide-wrap">
            <div class="divide-bar"></div>
            <div class="scroll"><a href="#item1" class="scroll-arrow panel"></a></div>
        </div>

            </div>
        </div>



        <div id="item3" class="when-area">
            <a name="item3"></a>
            <div class="content">

                 <div class="schedule-header-wrap">
                    <div class="schedule-header-image"><div class="about-us-cleardiv"></div><h1>WHO ARE WE, AND WHAT DO WE DO?</h1></div>
                    <div class="schedule-pad"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="item4" class="news-area">
            <a name="item4"></a>
            <div class="content">

               <div class="in-the-news-header-wrap">
                    <div class="in-the-news-pad"></div>
                    <div class="in-the-news-header-image"><div class="in-the-news-cleardiv"></div><h1>DEVELOPMENTS &amp; INNOVATIONS IN SURGERY &amp; TREATMENT</h1></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="item5" class="links-area">
            <a name="item5"></a>
            <div class="content">

                 <div class="useful-links-header-wrap">
                    <div class="useful-links-header-image"><div class="useful-links-cleardiv"></div><h1>SUPPORT, SERVICES & RETAILERS</h1></div>
                    <div class="useful-links-pad"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="item6" class="contact-area">
            <a name="item6"></a>
            <div class="content">

                 <div class="get-in-touch-header-wrap">
                    <div class="get-in-touch-pad"></div>
                    <div class="get-in-touch-header-image"><div class="get-in-touch-cleardiv"></div><h1>SEND US AN E-MAIL OR POP A LETTER IN THE POST</h1></div>
                </div>

            </div>
             <div class="footer-wrapper">TEST</div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

However, I would like to say the site is looking quite nice.

Kpsuperplane

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, such a simple solution but something that had me tearing my hair out for the last two days. I'm new to this site,is there a way I can give you 'reputation' points of some how kind to thank you for your help? Thanks again.

Comment: @DanCUK89 Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) Just accept his answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. Also, once you get 15 reputation, you'll be able to vote up posts.

Comment: @DanCUK89 I would also like to say that site is looking very nice!! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. This site is awesome, I couldn't believe I got a response so quickly, and it was spot on. Thanks for your help guys!